# parameter for reducer will not update at dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-reducers

I think my code is correct, it goes to check QueryString is undefined. If yes, then 'thePath' get the value from a config file. If QueryString has a value(which means not undefined anymore) then let the value of 'thePath' be QueryString. And it works, but it does NOT get updated in the return(dispatch) part of the function.. why?

The function is used to set different actions based on the result of axios, which ultimately becomes a part of a reducer, and redux store.

```
export let fetchingBook = (QueryString) => {

    let thePath;
    if (QueryString === undefined) {
        thePath = process.env.REACT_APP_GATEWAY_BOOK_PATH
    }
    else
        if (QueryString !== undefined) {
            thePath = QueryString
    }
    
    console.log("thePath : " + thePath);

    return (dispatch) => {

        console.log("came to return dispatch first time, does not come here the second time.. why?");

        dispatch(fetch_BOOK_Request())

        axios.get(thePath)
            .then(response => {
                const BookDATA = response.data
                dispatch(fetch_BOOK_Success(BookDATA))
            })
            .catch(error => {
                const ErrorMsg = error.message
                dispatch(fetch_BOOK_Failure(ErrorMsg))
            })
    }
}
```

UPDATE: where is it getting dispatched

```
const dispatching = dispatch => {
    return {
      // following is for another reducer
      goFindByPlanNumber__functionalProp: planNum => dispatch({ type: "SEARCH_BY_PLAN_NUMBER", txt: planNum }, fetchingBook(planNum)),
       //calling or dispatching fetchingBook here. it was added in the component using import
      fetchingBook__functionalProp:(planNum)=> dispatch(fetchingBook(planNum))
  
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: Where do you get dispatch inside your function context ? Your function only receives QueryString as parameter

Comment: @VítorFrança I've updated the code, thank you

Comment: If that is [mapDispatchToProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops) then you're doing something wrong. The [dispatch](https://redux.js.org/api/store/#dispatchaction) function only takes one argument. And as a tip; you can set a max line length in the editor that isn't insane.

Comment: @HMR yes this is a mapDispatchtoProps, i just renamed it to dispatching. that's what I'm trying to figure outr what am i doing wrong. :/

Comment: @adnantariq Added an answer with react redux thunk example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example of how to do async actions using redux thunk (I made middleware that behaves thunk like)

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = Redux;
const defaultState = { val: 0 };
const store = createStore(
  (state = defaultState, action) => {
    //reducer
    if (action.type === 'OK') {
      return {
        ...state,
        val: state.val + 1,
      };
    }
    if (action.type === 'DATA') {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    }
    return state;
  },
  defaultState,
  //somple redux thunk like middleware
  applyMiddleware(store => next => action => {
    if (typeof action === 'function') {
      return action(store.dispatch, store.getState);
    }
    return next(action);
  })
);
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { selectedId: 0 };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.action}>
            {this.props.val}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <select
            value={this.state.selectedId}
            onChange={e => {
              this.setState({ selectedId: e.target.value });
              this.props.getData(e.target.value);
            }}
          >
            <option value={0}>select id</option>
            {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(id => (
              <option key={id} value={id}>
                {id}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div>
          data is:{' '}
          {JSON.stringify(this.props.data, undefined, 2)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const ConnectedApp = connect(
  state => ({ val: state.val, data: state.data }), //map state to props
  {
    //map dispatch to props
    action: () => (dispatch, getState) => {
      //thunk like action
      console.log(
        'in action, current state is',
        getState()
      );
      dispatch({ type: 'OK' });
      let timesExecuted = 0;
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        timesExecuted++;
        dispatch({ type: 'OK' });
        if (timesExecuted > 3) {
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }, 1000);
    },
    getData: id => dispatch => {//get data action
      //you can dispatch loading action
      fetch(
        `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data =>
          dispatch({ type: 'DATA', payload: data })
        );
    },
  }
)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, I say this respectfully, that a bit confusing for me... but it seems like i cannot do this without actions creators. I will review your code in much more details later, may be even reach out to you if that's ok. anyways cheers.... by the way, are you dressed in Traditional Indian ? :)

Comment: @adnantariq No problem. The way redux works is that an action is dispatched and a reducer handles it synchronously. So when you need to do asynchronous stuff (like fetching data) you can use [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation) (it is the simplest one).